# Meteor MongoDB find / fetch issues

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
Meteor.publish('polls', function () { 
    return Polls.find({}); 
});

Meteor.publish('recentPolls', function() {
    return Polls.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 10}).fetch();
});
```

So this is in my `/server/server.js` file from the documentation it says the `fetch()` method returns matched documents in an array. However, using the subscribe function in the client like so

```
Template.recentPolls.polls = function() {
    console.log(Meteor.subscribe('recentPolls'));
    return Meteor.subscribe('recentPolls');
}
```

For some odd reason this is returning the following object (not an array) but an object

```
Object {stop: function, ready: function}
```

And this is the error I get in the console.

```
Exception from sub 5NozeQwianv2DL2eo Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
```

Answer (score 4):

`fetch` returns an array of objects, which isn't a legal value to return from a publish function.

Publish functions can only return a cursor, an array of cursors, or a falsy value. To fix your error, just remove the `fetch`:

```js
return Polls.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 10});
```

On the client you **do not** want to subscribe inside of your templates. You want to either subscribe once (usually in a file called `client/subscriptions.js`) or inside of your route (see the iron-router [documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)).

Ignore whatever the `subscribe` returns. Calling `subscribe` just allows the server to sync data to the client. The result of the call is not the data itself.

To access your data from your template, just use another find like:

```js
Template.recentPolls.polls = function() {
  Polls.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}});
}
```

Comment: That just returns the cursor correct? How would I go about accessing the data in the client?

Comment: This is the error I get in the console:

`Error: {{#each}} only accepts arrays, cursors, or falsey values. You passed: [object Object]`

Comment: The issue is that it's still returning the same object.

`console.log(Meteor.subscribe('recentPolls'));` returns the same object `Object {stop: function, ready: function}`

Comment: Yes, `find` returns a cursor. I updated the answer - see if any of that helps. Please make sure `Polls` is defined on both the client and the server.

Comment: This solved my problem, which was the same error. I was subscribing in a `RouteController` and returning that data to the template. It worked when I moved the subscribe to a global call and changed the controller to a simple `find()`.