# Adding information from another mongodb collection before providing the data via meteor's publish method

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

What I want to accomplish on http://crowducate.me:

- Display the usernames of the course authors (i.e. "owner" of a document).

Current Code:

```
Meteor.publish 'popularCourses', ->
# find all courses
  courses = Course.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch()
  for course in courses
# find each User by course owner
    owner = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: course.owner})
# overwrite the ownerId with the desired username
    course.owner = owner.username
  return courses
```

If I turn *autopublish* on, it works. The image shows the current status (autopublish *off*). As seen in the image, the author's name is only rendered if the current user is the same as the author.

[image]

--

A friend suggested the following:
https://gist.github.com/wiesson/1fd93d77ed9df353b7ab

> "The basic idea was to attach the username to the course before providing the data with the publish method. However, as described in [Meteor MongoDB find / fetch issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119873/meteor-mongodb-find-fetch-issues), the publish method should return a curser and not an array of objects.”

Any ideas how to solve that? Putting the owner usernames in an array? If so, how?

P.S.: Sourecode can be found here (currently, has more commits than the deployed version):
https://github.com/Crowducate/crowducate.me

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can accomplish this join. A few notes before before we begin:

- As I explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153349/meteor-subscribe-doesnt-update-sort-order-of-collection), sorting in the publish function has no affect on the order of documents on the client.
- Using the plural form in a collection name is the accepted standard. `Course` just looks odd when the collection contains courses.
- This question is fundamentally about joins, so I'd recommend reading [Reactive Joins In Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/).

### Server Transform

The literal answer to your question is to transform the documents on the server like so:

```
Meteor.publish 'popularCourses', ->
  transform = (fields) ->
    if fields.owner
      username = Meteor.users.findOne(fields.owner)?.username
      fields.owner = username
    fields

  handle = Course.find().observeChanges
    added: (id, fields) =>
      @added 'course', id, transform fields

    changed: (id, fields) =>
      @changed 'course', id, transform fields

    removed: (id) =>
      @removed 'course', id

  @ready()

  @onStop ->
    handle.stop()
```

#### Advantages

- All of the work is done on the server, so the client can just use `owner` as if it was a username.

#### Disadvantages

- Using `observeChanges` is probably more computational work than a simple join deserves.
- If you publish courses somewhere else, it's entirely likely that `owner` will be overwritten when the documents are merged on the client. This can be countered by appending a field like `ownerUsername` but that would also require a more expensive observe.
- This isn't helpful if you actually need the owner id somewhere on the client.
- It isn't reactive if the username changes (probably rare but figured I'd point that out).

### Non-Reactive Publish + Client Join

You could implement the publish like this:

#### CoffeeScript

```
Meteor.publish 'popularCourses', ->
  courseCursor = Course.find()
  userIds = courseCursor.map (c) -> c.owner
  userCursor = Meteor.users.find {_id: $in: userIds}, {fields: username: 1}
  [courseCursor, userCursor]
```

#### JavaScript

```
Meteor.publish('popularCourses', function() {
  var courseCursor = Course.find();
  var userIds = courseCursor.map(function(c) {return c.owner;});
  var userCursor = Meteor.users.find(
    {_id: {$in: userIds}}, 
    {fields: {username: 1}
  });
  return [courseCursor, userCursor];
});
```

Note that I'm being careful to only publish the `username` and `_id` from `userCursor` (you don't want to publish the hashed password and session data by accident). Then you can join the two collections on the client like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers
  courses: ->
    Course.find().map (c) ->
      c.owner = Meteor.users.findOne(c.owner)?.username
      c
```

#### Advantages

- Computationally light-weight and simple publish function.
- Reactive if the username changes.

#### Disadvantages

- Not reactive if the owner changes.
- You'll need to do the join on the client. An interesting alternative is to use something like [Collection Helpers](https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers).

Finally, I'll point out that you can use a package to do a fully reactive join. However, unless the owner (or owner's username) is changing a lot then this is probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm not that familiar with Coffeescript, however I thought the Publish method have to return a cursor. If I use your code, it does not work, so give me a short hint ;)

Comment: Sorry about that - I usually try to give answers in the same dialect as the question. Note: 1) coffeescript has implicit returns so I'm returning an array from the publish function, 2) publish functions can return a cursor or an array of cursors. The code I gave is nearly identical to the first example javascript [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/), so you can use that as a guide.

Comment: Amir is more familiar with coffeescript than me, however we are both trying to understand the problem. I don't understand how you are returning a cursor (or a list or cursers). Have you seen the router? https://github.com/Crowducate/crowducate.me/blob/master/client/router/routes.coffee#L203-L207 - is this with your adjustments still correct?

Comment: I updated the answer with the JS version of the publish function. Does that help answer the question? It really doesn't have anything to do with your router since we are still publishing courses... we just also happen to be publishing some users as well. The `waitOn` should still work. I'm not sure what's going on in your `data` section but I'm not familiar with `minimongoid`.

Comment: @DavidWeldon: This has helped a lot. Thanks a lot for your time. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to just publish both `popularCourses` and `owners` and add the owner to each course on the client (with the exact same code you have written on the publication).

Comment: Will try tomorrow and let you know. Thx!